# How to draw a diagram with arrows in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

[image: Diagram to show arrows are wrong]

I tried to draw a diagram. I won't change this one. But I need to draw a new diagram. This time the arrows aren't allowed to hide under the circle - or in the case of the new diagram: under the box.

How do I connect multiple boxes with an arrow?

Example of how a diagram can look like: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Donald-Weller/publication/46644603/figure/fig2/AS:669214092308483@1536564481152/Box-and-arrow-diagram-showing-the-organizational-structure-of-the-project-The-three.png

Please don't draw an entire diagram for me. It would be a waste of your time. I just need to know how to connect multiple boxes with arrows.

Thanks so much for your time and effort!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Inkscape 1.2 you can offset arrow markers using the *Offset X* value in the Markers dropdown, just enough to pull it back from the line of an object.

You can also use the Diagram Connectors tool [image] to connect shapes with lines so that they can move automatically when you move the connected objects.

An example

[image]

Comment: You can also go to symbols and use the logical or diagram simbols over there, then conect them just as in the answer.

Comment: @SIMBIOSISsurl - perhaps, but this question is about arrow heads, how to move them, and how to connect arrows to objects, nothing really to do with diagram symbols.  You need to pay attention to the actual question being asked.